# Yup conditional validation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, formik, yup

I want to validate one field on the basis of other using my schema. Like, if carType is "SUV" maximum "noOfPassengers" should be 6 else 4. But, it's not validating this case, neither I can debug this nor getting any error in console.

```
const validationSchema = yup.object().shape({
    location: yup
        .string()
        .required('location is required'),
    destination: yup
        .string()
        .required('Destination is required'),
    carType: yup
        .string(),
    noOfPassengers: yup
        .string()
        .when('carType', {
            is: value => value && value === "SUV",
            then: yup
                .string()
                .max(6, 'Max 6 passengers are required'),
            otherwise: yup
                .string()
                .max(4, 'Max 4 passengers are required'),
        }),
});
```

Comment: can you share your form code ?

Comment: Did you try simply `is: 'SUV'`?

Answer (score 5):

You are comparing the values of noOfPassengers as string while it should be a number something like this:

```
Yup.object().shape({
  location: Yup
      .string()
      .required('location is required'),
  destination: Yup
      .string()
      .required('Destination is required'),
  carType: Yup
      .string(),
  noOfPassengers: Yup
      .number()
      .when('carType', {
          is: value => value && value === "SUV",
          then: Yup
              .number()
              .max(6, 'Max 6 passengers are required'),
          otherwise: Yup
              .number()
              .max(4, 'Max 4 passengers are required'),
      }),
});
```

If you run this you should get validation error. You have a flaw in logical condition as well. You should fix that too but that isn't the scope of this answer.

The problem is

`Yup.string()` should be `Yup.number()` because you are then comparing it in `max`.

Comment: Got my mistake, it worked for me. Thanks !

Comment: Cool. you can accept the answer if it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that for more complex validation you encounter an error unless you have the then as a callback.

```
eventEndDate: Yup.string().when('dateSelector', {
    is: 'selected',
    then: () =>
      Yup.string()
        .matches(
          /^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/\d{2}$/,
          "You're date needs to be in the following format: dd/mm/yy. Eg: 24/12/23",
          { excludeEmptyString: true }
        )
        .required('End date is a required field.'),
  }),
```